# exact match a string in a variable with a string in another

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, shell

I have a sentence which is nothing but a string variable with words separated by spaces .

I have another variable which contains a word . What I wanted is to find exact matching of the word in the variable containing the sentence . I have tried this :

```
read -p "enter the word to match " STR # STR contains VVDNSG 

#this DUP_SG_NAME_PUBLIC variable contains a string which consists of few words 
DUP_SG_NAME_PUBLIC=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups \
  --query 'SecurityGroups[*].{GroupName:GroupName}' \
  --output text) 

if [[ $DUP_SG_NAME_PUBLIC =~ $STR ]]
then 
echo "true"
else 
echo "false"
fi
```

**Problem**
Here I have provided "VVDN" as string but I have to match "VVDNSG" but this code works for both . Even for VVDN and VVDNSG which is understandable .

**What I want to do**
I want to find exact match that is if given VVDNSG as STR value it should print true or else false even with VVDN and I want that to do the comparison with variables not with literal strings .

I have tried few examples googling most of them either tell you to find match in a file or hardcode the string comparison.

Comment: Seems like a `case` with an exact match first and a wildcard match second might be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your `STR` works as a regex. So, to use it as an exact match, explicitly mark the beginning with `^`and the end with `$`:

```
STR="^VVDN$"
```

Then the `if` condition will be true only for exact matches of `STR` in `DUP_SG_NAME_PUBLIC`.

**Update**:
Actually, I think what you want is somewhat different - you have a sentence containing words separated by spaces (you didn't mention a termination character) and you want to match one of the words, only if it is an exact match. Let's assume it will be an exact match if it has a space after the word or if it is at the end of the sentence.

In that case, your regex could be:

```
STR="VVDN($| )"
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes you are right , I have a sentence containing words stored in variable and I want to match one of the words only if it is an exact match . Let me check your solution .Problem is I take input from the user to be stored in STR variable . I  know that ^ and $ mark the begin and end but only if I could use them in user input . I have edited the question.

Comment: I am a little sketchy on awk and sed , I don't know if these tools could work here .

Comment: After storing the input from the user you can always append something to it. For example, you can do `STR="${STR}($| )"`. If you want the exact match to be extended to the whole word, which means the match could happen at the beginning of the sentence or when there's a space before the match, you could change it to `STR="(^| )${STR}($| )"`.